# How to build -debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk in gradle task

Tags: android, android-espresso

in android studio, when i run espresso test, console output:

```
Installing APK: /home/roroco/Dropbox/jvs/ro-adr/testStartApp/build/outputs/apk/testStartApp-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/ro.testStartApp.test
Installing ro.testStartApp.test
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/ro.testStartApp.test"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/ro.testStartApp.test
Success
```

but when i rm build/ and run gradle assembleDebug, the "testStartApp-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk" doesn't exist like following:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/jvs/ro-adr/testStartApp $ lsa /home/roroco/Dropbox/jvs/ro-adr/testStartApp/build/outputs/apk
total 9496
drwxr-xr-x 2 roroco roroco    4096 May 21 23:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 roroco roroco    4096 May 21 23:40 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 roroco roroco 3237948 May 21 23:08 testStartApp-debug.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 roroco roroco 3237559 May 21 23:08 testStartApp-debug-unaligned.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 roroco roroco 3211410 May 21 23:08 testStartApp-release-unsigned.apk
```

which gradle task can generate "testStartApp-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk"?

Answer (score 1):

When I list tasks:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Dropbox/jvs/ro-adr/testStartApp $ gd tasks|gr assemble
assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages.
assembleAndroidTest - Assembles all the Test applications.
assembleDebug - Assembles all Debug builds.
assembleRelease - Assembles all Release builds.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.
buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
Pattern: build<ConfigurationName>: Assembles the artifacts of a configuration.
Pattern: upload<ConfigurationName>: Assembles and uploads the artifacts belonging to a configuration.
```

it's assembleAndroidTest